# Auto Reload the Google page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want my html code to open the Google Page and refresh it after every 5 seconds.
The Code i have written, it opens the google page after 5 seconds but it doesn't refresh or reload it again. How can I do that?

Here is the Code:

```
<html>

<head> 
    <script>

        setInterval(function(){
        window.location.href ="https://www.google.com.pk/"; 
        }, 5000);

    </script>   

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot refresh a page that is not your own, unless its in an iframe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244877/refresh-an-iframe

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by iframe ?

Comment: And iframe is a dom element that allows you to show another webpage inside yours. https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/iframe

Comment: okay so is it possible for me to use iframe tag and to refer it to google. hence it will reload the google page in the loop right ?

Comment: Yes, just take a look at a good way to do that in the question I linked to in my first comment. The answer is `use an iframe, and refresh that every 5 seconds.`

Answer (score 0):

when you refresh the webpage by javascript, the browser will be redirected to google.com and would not be able to read your code. So the best way to this is  to create a iframe in your html, and reload it by javascript.

because the reloading a iframe would not redirect your whole page to a new domain, your js code will still exist and able to run :

```
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe src="http://www.google.com" id="googleIframe"></iframe>
 <script>
document.getElementById('googleIframe').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code won't run. You'll get an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: Sorry just missed the string in getElementById

Comment: You probably want to put the refresh in an interval for OP as well. I'll +1 it after you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Take away the semi colon after your Web address and remove the javascript entirely

Answer (score -1):

You will need to have Google in an iframe then have the following code in you HTML file head:

```
   <head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
```

Comment: This is not that great of a solution as it requires the entire page the user is on the be refreshed.

Comment: The OP seemed to ask for HTML code but used JS and failed. That soution is html only solution.

Comment: The OP asked for something that isn't possible, and it's obvious by his code that he was trying to use javascript, and this question is tagged with javascript.

Comment: This is the code that i have written. It is not showing google page.  But it is refreshing

Comment: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
 <body>
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com.pk/" id="googleIframe"></iframe>
 <script>
 document.getElementById('#googleIframe').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: The meta tag doesn't need the java script the entire page will refresh ever 5 seconds.

Comment: it is refreshing but its not opening the Google page

Comment: Take away the semi colon after your Web address and remove the javascript entirely

Comment: did that and its working. Though google logo and things related to it CSS are not visible but its fetching google.com at every refresh.

Comment: @Rmj86 is it because my html file doesnot have google page CSS thats why it is blank ?

Comment: Do you have .pk in you url? Remove that should help I think. Can you put a Screenshot up of what the page looks like?